# javascript window.onerror message contains only "Script error." how can i get the line number?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

you probably protect your js script by window.onerror to catch global exceptions,
the thing is, my files on production are compressed and the line number will be always 1 ,so i really don't know where is the error occurred? do you have any suggestion what can i do in this case?

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, fileName, lineNumber) { logger.sendError(errorMsg + " file name " + fileName, "window.onerror") };
```

Comment: If your code is minified in a single line, you _are_ getting the only meaningful line number you can get. There is no way for the browser to guess how your code was laid out before it was minified.

Comment: Isn't that nonsensical to develop your project on compressed files? (if compressed files are yours). You can beautify your js files, http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: i have both source file and compressed file on the server, i'm looking for a way to replace the compressed file with the beautify one in case of exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ianzz says in his comment, in general it will be impossible for your browser to determine a meaningful line number for minified code. After all: if all code is on a single line, the correct (but quite useless) line number is always `1`.

There is a movement however to allow the use of source maps, which are separate files that specify exactly how the (minified) JavaScript maps back to more meaningful input.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

The specification is relatively new and not too far spread yet. But depending on your minification framework, there may be a tool available already to generate source maps.

Answer (score 0):

If it says "Script error" then the browser has prevented your error handling code from accessing the stack due to a CSP (Content Security Policy) violation.

Usually this happens if your code comes from a different domain, or if it uses eval or JSONP.

Most bundlers (e.g. browserify/webpack) use eval or JSONP by default. For webpack you can set `config.devtool` to change this.